# How to implement Hough transform for circle detection without using cv2.HoughCircle in python

Tags: python, image-processing, hough-transform

I understand the basic steps/concept I believe

1. Use some kind of edge detection (canny, etc)
2. Put this image through a Hough Circle algorithm that is created
3. Then draw the circles over the original image to show detection

I don't understand how to implement step 2 from 1 and thus am unable to even draw the circles.

When I use the cv2.hough circles the circle drawn aren't connected to any kind of cell/circle which makes me think something is wrong with the edge detection

Comment: Debated between putting in in a comment or an answer.  I implemented Hough Circle (and Hough Line) for one of my senior theses rather more years ago than I care to think about ... what I remember is A) Step 1a is to to apply a threshold to convert from edges to a binary image and then Step 2 is basically a matter of going through each 1 (edge) and using that to vote for which circles this could be a part of, and then pick out the top N highest vote getters ... are you trying to implement Hough Circle yourself or figure out why OpenCV isn't working?

Comment: I'm trying implement it without using the opencv package. More of like an exercise of Understanding, via detection of one object that is a circle shape.

Comment: If I could find my text book I'd recommend it if you wanted to start from first principals, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform seems like a reasonable starting point.  As written, this isn't a great question for this site; I'd suggest trying to implement the algorithm using some simple images and if you can post your current attempt and what you're getting back, that would be something that people could help with.